# Test of a service using ngx-restangular not working

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, restangular, angular5

I'm working on an Angular 5 app using ngx-restangular.

I have created a service in which the http calls are made using ngx-restangular. Following is the service code -

**Project.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Restangular } from 'ngx-restangular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {

    constructor(public restangular: Restangular) {}

    restoreProject(project): Observable<any> {
        return this.restangular.one('projects', project.id).get(); 
    }

}
```

Following is the test in Jasmine for the above service -

**Project.service.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Restangular } from 'ngx-restangular';
import { HttpModule, Http, BaseRequestOptions, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';

import {ProjectService } from './project.service';

describe('ProjectService', () => {
    let service = ' ';

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                ProjectService,
                { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend }
            ]
        });
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        service = new ProjectService(Restangular);
    });

    describe('restoreProject method', () => {

        let connection = '';

        beforeEach(inject([XHRBackend], (MockBackend) => {
            MockBackend.connections.subscribe((httpConnection: any) => connection = httpConnection);
        }));

        it('should query restore project', () => {      
            service.restoreProject({id: 2});
            expect(connection.request.url).toMatch('projects/2', 'url invalid');
        });
    })    
});
```

I'm using Karma test-runner. On running the test, it outputs

`this.restangular.one is not a function`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, referred to https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/11/28/testing-services-with-http-in-angular-2.html#testing-the-service

The project service had dependencies hence was not supposed to be initialised like
    `let service = new ProjectService()`

Required a proper testbed config (with restangular) and injection of the ProjectService in every test